# What is the best way to initialize huge constant multidimensional arrays that are not integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization-list

I'm trying to warp adapted functions of the [*solar position algorithm*](https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/spa/#register)(aka "*spa*") made by the United States Naval Observatory to my code in a class so I can easily just call on one method to compute the solar positions.

This code belows is from the source code by the USNO. I am trying to initialize the lists **L_TERMS, B_TERMS and R_TERMS**

```
#define L_COUNT 6
#define B_COUNT 2
#define R_COUNT 5
#define Y_COUNT 63

#define L_MAX_SUBCOUNT 64
#define B_MAX_SUBCOUNT 5
#define R_MAX_SUBCOUNT 40

enum {TERM_A, TERM_B, TERM_C, TERM_COUNT};
enum {TERM_X0, TERM_X1, TERM_X2, TERM_X3, TERM_X4, TERM_X_COUNT};
enum {TERM_PSI_A, TERM_PSI_B, TERM_EPS_C, TERM_EPS_D, TERM_PE_COUNT};
enum {JD_MINUS, JD_ZERO, JD_PLUS, JD_COUNT};
enum {SUN_TRANSIT, SUN_RISE, SUN_SET, SUN_COUNT};

#define TERM_Y_COUNT TERM_X_COUNT

const int l_subcount[L_COUNT] = {64,34,20,7,3,1};
const int b_subcount[B_COUNT] = {5,2};
const int r_subcount[R_COUNT] = {40,10,6,2,1};

const double L_TERMS[L_COUNT][L_MAX_SUBCOUNT][TERM_COUNT]=
 { ... }; // contains 3*(64+34+20+7+3+1) = 387 doubles
const double B_TERMS[B_COUNT][B_MAX_SUBCOUNT][TERM_COUNT]=
 { ... }; // contains 3*(5+2) = 21 doubles
const double R_TERMS[R_COUNT][R_MAX_SUBCOUNT][TERM_COUNT]=
 { ... }; // contains 3*(40+10+6+2+1) = 177 doubles
```

I'm having trouble however initializing the arrays with the constructor. I tried using an initialization list but it doesn't seem to work. If I initialize the arrays in the constructor, all is well but won't be on the scope of the other methods since I can't declare them in the header. I can't initialize them either like a *const int array*.

Is there a better way to initialize multidimensional const double array that I am not aware of?

Note: the source code written by the USNO was done in C but I'm trying to use it in C++. Should I just include their file and call on the computing function?

Comment: Tip: Don't use arrays, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Tip: Use existing matrix libraries.

Comment: You need to use three `{`'s, like `const double L_TERMS[...][...][...] = { { { 1.0, ... }, { .... } .... } }`, because it is a 3D array. Btw, these arrays are far from huge.

Comment: @tadman why should one use a `vector` instead of an array of known size????

Comment: @Swordfish Because it's a Standard Library container and not some C anachronism. Because it has a lot of handy helper functions, like filling it with certain values on creation. Because there's other containers more optimized for different situations which might work better, yet have largely the same interface. Because you can pass it in by reference and the receiving function won't need to know in advance what size it is.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `const` in preference to `#define`. This provides type-safety among other benefits.

Comment: Try using a `std::array` instead.

Comment: @tadman: `std::vector` is bad for this purpose. `std::array` is better.

Comment: @geza `std::vector` is a good place to start, but yes, `std::array` is better if this is fixed-length.

Comment: @tadman no need for your writeup. the point is you were suggesting a container for a variable amount of items as a replacement for a fixed size array.

Comment: @Swordfish `std::vector` works even if it's not ideal. `std::array`, as others have pointed out, is better.

Comment: @tadman I was considering using vector too but I am not so familiar with iterating through one, is it the same as arrays? Also can you initiliaze in the initialization list?

Comment: There's various containers, each of which have different properties. `std::vector` is a good place to start, it's very versatile, but there are others more specialized like [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which is fixed length. You can initialize it the same as regular arrays, but you get a suite of iterators to operate on it plus things like `for (const auto& value : my_array)`.

Comment: If you're going to go down the C-array road, it'd make sense to declare a `typedef` with a predictable size or even `struct` to act as a container for the data. A `struct` can have a constructor that does any messy pre-population work.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can use an initializer list. What I like to do when doing this kind of thing is start much smaller though. Start with just much smaller arrays so it's easier to manage.

```
int main()
{
    const double d[2][3][4] =
    {
        {
            { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 },
            { 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 },
            { 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 }
        },
        {
            { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 },
            { 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 },
            { 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 }
        },
    };
}
```

Here we declare `d` to be 2 x 3 x 4. So we can use `d[0]` and `d[1]`, and `d[0][2]` and `d[1][2][3]` is the last element.

Here's what various things print, noting I've been lazy and just declared the outer arrays with the same elements:

```
std::cout << d[0][0][0] << ", " << d[1][0][0] << "\n"; // prints 0.1, 0.1
std::cout << d[0][2][3] << ", " << d[1][2][3] << "\n"; // prints 1.2, 1.2
std::cout << d[0][1][2] << ", " << d[1][1][2] << "\n"; // prints 0.7, 0.7
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer. Note there's no reason to leave lines like I have, I just find it is easier to read.

Comment: I can understand that much. But how would you do it in a class? It has to be declared in the header so every methods can read it, but can only be defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out in the initialization list, you can either use () or {}, not ({}). So for example initializing an array should be done with the following line:

```
class Foo::Foo() : L_TERMS{{{ ... }}}, // rest of initialization
```

Rather than

```
class Foo::Foo() : L_TERMS( {{{ ... }}} ) // rest of initialization
```